# UITableview blocking uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiview

So I had a UITableView that I tried to make smaller by adjusting its constraints. I then added three labels and textfields to my UIView. However, upon running the app the UITableView doesn't seem to have been made smaller, instead it's "overlapping" my labels and textfields. Here is a picture of what I am describing. http://imgur.com/BoC6l1R. And here is a picture of the storyboard editor. Note the dotted lines. http://imgur.com/wUyccDk. I've tried changing many things with the constraints but they all make everything more messed up. I feel like the solution should be pretty simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second image (the storyboard) you see there's a dotted line and a yellow line with +78. That indicated that the constraint specifies that the table view should be 78 points above where it is now. That's a warning in your storyboard meaning that the UITableView will appear in a different position at runtime.
The easiest way to solve it is to open the storyboard file, then at your left there should be the Document Outline. Find your view controller, and there should be a small yellow arrow next to the view controller name. Click on it and you'll go to a screen showing you the constraint warnings. It should say "Misplaced views". Click on the small yellow arrow next to the misplaced view (your UITableView) and a popup will appear. Select "Update Constraints" and then click on "Fix misplacement". That should do it.

However, a better way to solve it is to put a constraint between your text fields and the UITableView. Delete the constraint between the table view and the top layout guide (the one appearing yellow), then add a Vertical Spacing constraint between the UITableView and the UITextField below the Sea_State label.

Comment: My recommendation is to go with the second solution then. I assume you're trying to have a vertical space between the table view and the last text field, so do that. Delete the current constraint (between the UITableView and the top layout guide). Then in the Document Online (storyboard), select the UITableView, hold Ctrl and drag your mouse to the UITextField (the one below the label Sea_State). A popup will appear, select Vertical Spacing. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Sorry the first solution actually worked, I just forgot to hit "Update Constraints" Thanks!